# What ongoing maintenance is needed for a MySQL environment?

Tags: mysql

I'm an MSSQL DBA, and I'm inheriting a 3-server MySQL 5.6 environment feeding a (currently) low traffic website.  I'm having a hard time finding what kind of regular / preventative maintenance a MySQL env needs.  I've done a fair amount of self-studying, but the guides etc I've run across mainly talk about installation and backups.  My environment is installed, and we have backups going.  Now what?

So what sort of care and feeding does a MySQL environment need?  Corruption checks?  Index rebuilds?  Aromatherapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It just works!**

Seriously though, if you got a master with two replicas environment, you probably want to do occasional consistency checks with [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html). Replication does not guarantee consistency (and writes can happen on replicas too).

Otherwise:

1. Verify your backups to make sure you can actually recover (most of our data recovery customers thought they have backups, but they were actually not working).
2. [Query reviews](http://www.speedemy.com/advanced-mysql-slow-query-logging-1/) - definitely worth learning how to do that so you can review them proactively.
3. Do check error logs - any corruption errors will show up there.

There are many other things you can do, but I try to live by the rule: **don't fix what ain't broken**.

Good luck!